# Detect if Application has Dialog Box Open

Tags: excel, vb.net

Example: I have running Excel instance with active workbook and worksheet. Trying to get Used Range of my active worksheet. When I have no dialog box open, my VB.net code detects range BUT if I have any dialog window open for example Find and Replace or Format Cells etc. it fails to select used range and I get error.

I am thinking to solve this issue by detecting if any dialog boxes are open if so just exit function with message to close close dialogs.

```
  Public Function GetActiveExcelWorksheet() As Excel.Worksheet

        Dim excel As Excel.Application
        Dim activeWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing

        Dim ExcelInstances As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName("EXCEL")
        If ExcelInstances.Count() = 0 Then
            Exit Function
        End If

        excel = TryCast(Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application"), Excel.Application)
        If excel Is Nothing Then Exit Function

        Dim activeWorkook As Excel.Workbook = excel.ActiveWorkbook
        Dim activeSheet As Object = excel.ActiveSheet
        activeWorksheet = TryCast(activeSheet, Excel.Worksheet)

        Return activeWorksheet

    End Function


Public Sub ImportBlocks()

    Dim eu As New ExcelUtil()
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet = Nothing
    Dim xr As Excel.Range
    Dim rowsCount As Integer = 0
    Dim columnsCount As Integer = 0

    ' Try to get Active Excel Worksheet
    ws = eu.GetActiveExcelWorksheet()

    ' If Excel Worksheet is NOT Found Exit Sub-Function with Error
    If ws Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Active EXCEL Worksheet was NOT Found.", vbExclamation Or vbOKOnly Or vbApplicationModal, "Block Import Warning")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ' FAILS HERE IF DIALOG OPEN
    xr = ws.UsedRange
    rowsCount = xr.Rows.Count
    columnsCount = xr.Columns.Count
```

Comment: Please don't tag your post C# if it doesn't contain C# code.

Comment: Try getting the style of the main Excel window and check if it is WS_DISABLED.  If so then a dialog is open.

Comment: "I get an error" is a good way to detect this.  Use Try/Catch

Comment: How I can get style of window?